# How do I add a css class to the text box using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to add a class to this text box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text-element').on('click', function(event){
        var textBox = document.createElement('input');
        textBox.type = 'text';
        document.getElementById('titlebox').appendChild(textBox);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you included [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) on your page? If not, what scripts *do* you have in place to make things resizeable and draggable, and what classes do those scripts expect?

Comment: You'll generally need to initialize on the object in question if you are inserting into the DOM after the page load. Also, your title is about adding a class, but your question is about making something draggable/resizable. Not sure what you want.

Comment: JQuery UI is included in my work. So i'm not sure where my work is wrong. I'll make a JSFiddle and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some like that

```
textBox.className = 'some-name';
```

Comment: Did you read the whole question or only the title?

Comment: In his defense he answered one of my questions.

Comment: Then I will remove my downvote ;)

Comment: Apparently he answered the only question. You are asking how to add a class to the input so you can make it draggable and resizable. The question don't make it clear that you are having trouble with the jquery ui plugins.

Comment: It was a poorly constructed question. That was my fault. Thanks for the help nonetheless!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to add a class to the element.  For example:

```
$(textBox).addClass('box-element');
```